# How do I find the kernel of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question I'm working on is asking me to find the kernel of a linear transformation of P₂(t) to P1(t). The transformation is defined by L(p(t))=tp"(t).

I know that P2 is at most degree 2, and P1 is at most degree 1, I'm used to finding the kernel by using vectors and I've found [this page is helpful](https://www.nibcode.com/en/linear-algebra/kernel-of-a-linear-transformation) but I haven't been able to find any sources on how I'm supposed to find the kernel with P(t). is it {x^2 + x +1} or is it supposed to be formatted {x^2, x, 1} (I want clarification on how these are supposed to be formatted into vectors)?

I am also confused on what tp"(t) is supposed to look like? Is it times t of t?

Any clarification would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Take a general 'vector' in $P_2(t)$. This is any polynomial of the form $at^2+bt+c$. What happens to this vector under L? When is that result the 0 polynomial?

Comment: If I understand well the problem the linear transformation $L$ is defined by
$$L(ax^2+bx+c)=t(2a)$$ Consequently the kernel would be all the space of polynomials $ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: @Piquito I suppose you mean $bt+c$? The computation you just did shows that $a=0$ must be imposed for $at^2+bt+c\in \ker(L)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in polynomials over the variable $t$. In particular, $t$ itself is a polynomial. If $p$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$, then its second derivative $p''$ is also a polynomial of degree at most $0$, i.e., a number. So by multiplying the two polynomials $t$ and $p''$, you get the polynomial $tp'' = L(p)$.

The kernel of your linear map is defined as the set of inputs which are mapped to $0$ by $L$. (In this context, $0$ is the zero polynomial). So you want to find the set of all polynmials $p\in P_2(t)$ such that $tp''=0$.

A polynomial is equal to $0$ if and only if all its coefficients are $0$. In this case, since $p''$ is just a number, it is actually the $t$-coefficient of $L(p)$.
So for any $p\in P_2(t)$, you have $L(p)=0 \iff p'' = 0$. So the only remaining question is: Which polynomials in $P_2(t)$ have $0$ as their second derivative? Let's just look at a general quadratic polynomial, say $p=at^2+bt+c$. Then $p'=2at+b$ and $p''=2a$. So in fact, $p''=0 \iff a=0 \iff p\in P_1(t)$.

$$\ker(L) = \{ p\in P_2(t) \mid L(p) = 0 \} = \{p\in P_2(t) \mid p''= 0\} = P_1(t)          $$

Comment: Thank you so much!